# How to get 2 lines that present the characters but have different binary values to be recognized as duplicates by uniq

Tags: bash, uniq

I have 2 lines in a text file that both show Précilia.

> Précilia
>
> Précilia

However, the first line has the binary

> 01010000 01110010 01100101 1100000001 01100011 01101001 01101100 01101001 01100001

which shows an é in UTF-8 but not in ASCII because it uses 2 bytes to create the é character.
The second line has the binary

> 01010000 01110010 11101001 01100011 01101001 01101100 01101001 01100001

which presents as an é in both ASCII and UTF-8.
I am trying to compact a list of names and some have these different binary values but present the same characters to the eye.  Uniq will treat these two names as unique.  Is there a way to process this list so uniq will consider them the same?

I tried `tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < original.txt > cleaned.txt` but that created 2 different entries.

> Precilia
>
> Prcilia

Ideally I can find a solution that will work for a variety of these non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Are you sure about the first binary representation? `1100000001` has 10 bits.

Comment: Also, ASCII only has 128 code points. Bytes with the high order bit set are not used in ASCII. If 11101001 (0xE9, 233) renders as "é", the encoding is likely to be ISO-8859-1.

Comment: What does the `file` command say about the encoding of your input?

Comment: What you are asking for is a piece of software that "normalizes" your strings, i.e., it creates a "canonical" representation of each utf8 character in the sense that for a set of utf8 characters that all look the same it selects one representative of that set.
I believe ICU's normalization (http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/normalization) will do what you want.
You might want to read this page, too: https://withblue.ink/2019/03/11/why-you-need-to-normalize-unicode-strings.html

Comment: @LaszloLadanyi, that second link explained things perfectly.  Thank you!